# Analytics dispatcher and configuration management for custom usage

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, analytics

I am looking for a component that would act as an event dispatcher for Android Analytics or for a whole custom Analytics solution.

I found some pretty neat code from the recently released [Parse Android SDK](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android).
I will use some part of it, if no other solution will appear.
But maybe there is something simpler.

Ideally, I would like to have something similar to what [ARAnalytics](https://github.com/orta/ARAnalytics) is, plus some custom analytics/usage sender pointing to my service.

Are there any production-ready components for that?

Comment: I have used Flurry (https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/), and Google Analytics (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/). Google Analytics is so far the best analytics engine I have used. You can try it

Comment: @Shrikant I am also using Google Analytics. But it is not the case of choosing analytics solution. I need my own for specific purposes. It will coexist with Google Analytics. But it is question about engine that will dispatch all the events to my server in some predefined way.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
// Set the dispatch period in seconds.
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setLocalDispatchPeriod(30);
```

and also Google has introduced Firebase analytics google now recommends developer to use firebase refer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to send extra events and perform custom post-processing on those events.

You could use something like [PIWIK](http://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-api-clients) to track your custom events locally. Then you'd need to write a glue between your server and PIWIK (or write the functionality you desire as a PIWIK module).

Alternatively, you could sent events to [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com) and [export them](https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/exporting-raw-data-you-inserted-into-mixpanel) periodically to your server (e.g. in a cronjob). Then, your server can do whatever post-processing it needs to do.

As a side note, when I was experimenting with Google Analytics and Mixpanel, I wrote an (opinionated) analytics wrapper with specific methods (e.g. `sendError(...)`, `sendTimeDelta(...)`).